# MySQL - How to make more than 1 where clause on same column?

Tags: mysql

Well i'm trying to make a where clause on same column many times i.e:

```
  product
----------------------------------------
| product_id | product_name | group_id |
----------------------------------------

  group
-------------------------
| group_id | group_name |
-------------------------

  group_val
-------------------------
| group_id | product_id |
-------------------------


select b.product_name
from group_val a
inner join product b using(product_id) 
inner join group c using(group_id) 
where a.group_id in(10,15,88)
group by b.product_id;
```

it's same as `or ... or` but i need to do something like: it only will return product that are on group 10 and group 15 and group 88: I mean that a product need to be in these 3 groups.

i.e:

```
  group_val
-------------------------
| group_id | product_id |
-------------------------
| 10       | 1          |
-------------------------
| 15       | 1          |
-------------------------
| 88       | 1          |
-------------------------
| 15       | 2          |
-------------------------
| 10       | 2          |
-------------------------
```

In this case it will only return product `1`

How can I do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use SQL reserved words as table or column names (in your case *group*).

Comment: it's only a example ;p

Comment: Have you tried `and ... and` in place of `or ... or`?

Comment: @ultranaut yes, it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe a side issue, maybe not, but does `group_id` make sense as a field in your  `product` table? Isn't `group_val` what's associating a product with a particular group(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just working with your example query, and assuming that you explicity know, programmatically or otherwise, which `group_id`s you're looking to match and how many there are:

```
select `product_name`, count(gv.`product_id`) as cnt
from `product` p
left join `group_val` gv
on p.`product_id` = gv.`product_id`
where gv.`group_id` in (10, 15, 88)
group by p.`product_id`
having cnt = 3;
```

will select all the `product_id`s in `group_val` that is in all of those groups.

Comment: it worked but i need to use distinct on count(distinct(gv.product_id)), thanks ;p

Comment: @ultranaut I think your approach is better than mine, but it can be improved, see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b1d9/4)

Comment: @grahamj42 yeah, you don't really need to get the count back I guess

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the field group_id in table product

```
SELECT p.product_name
  FROM product AS p
    INNER JOIN group_val AS g1 ON p.product_id = g1.product_id
    INNER JOIN group_val AS g2 ON p.product_id = g2.product_id
    INNER JOIN group_val AS g3 ON p.product_id = g3.product_id
  WHERE g1.group_id = 10 AND g2.group_id = 15 AND g3.group_id=88;
```

Try it in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b1d9/1)